# locals() built-in method in Python3 returns the variable in the global namespace

Tags: python-3.x, scope

```
name = "Lenin Mishra"

def home():
    name = "Sonu"
    print(name)


home()
print(locals())
```

When I run the above code, Python returns me a dictionary containing the variable name, which has a value of `Lenin Mishra`.

```
{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': '\nExperimenting with scope\n', '__package__': None, '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x10323b400>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__file__': '/Users/leninmishra/Desktop/python_basics/scope.py', '__cached__': None, 'name': 'Lenin Mishra', 'home': <function home at 0x101db5e18>}
```

But as far as I understand, the variable name which has been assigned the value of `Lenin Mishra` is in the global scope.

Why is this happening?

Comment: because you are *calling it in the global scope*

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `locals()` executed at `global` scope, so you got that output.

If you execute that `locals()` as part of another function, you could get the local variables to that specific function's scope.

For example, if you write your code as below, you could get out-put as empty brackets.
python works based on indentation.

**Sample-code**

```
def myfun():
    print(locals())

myfun()
```

**Output**

```
{}
```

**Sample code2**

```
def home():
    name = "Sonu"
    print(locals())

home()
```

**output**

```
{'name': 'Sonu'}
```

This sample 2 code explains only name variable is available in its local scope.

**[Help](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) of locals function says as follows:**

```
In [1]: ?locals
Signature: locals()
Docstring:
Return a dictionary containing the current scope's local variables.

NOTE: Whether or not updates to this dictionary will affect name lookups in
the local scope and vice-versa is *implementation dependent* and not
covered by any backwards compatibility guarantees.
Type:      builtin_function_or_method
```